# Make lookup tables in Excel/VBA from a list of names with repeats

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names and instances in Excel in one sheet, and a list names and of user ID's in another. I want to make a column that references name and user ID on the instance sheet, however some of the user's have identical names. For a 1:1 matching I use a vlookup to get the  corresponding ID, but this doesn't work for multiple instances. What can I do to make a column that displays every possible ID associated with that name in the case of a Many:1 relationship? Example:

```
User Name:              User ID:
Rusty McShackleford     1234560
Rusty McShackleford     1234570
Rusty McShackleford     1234580
Rusty McShackleford     1230110
Zap Brannigan           0000001
```

In the example above, I can match Zap to a user ID because there is only one instance, how would I match Rusty (or all the Rusty's) to an instance. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spreadsheet layout:

`A2:A15` Names
`B2:B15` IDs
`D2` `{=INDEX($A$2:$A$15;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($D$1:D1;$A$2:$A$15);0))}`
Array formula, Ctrl-Shift-Enter in formula window to enter, curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user.
Lists unique names in `A2:A15`, should be copied down. The column can be hidden.

`E2`: Cell with a dropdown list, entry is selected from a list of names in column `D`
`F3`: `=F2+MATCH($E$2;OFFSET($A$1;F2+1;0):$A$15;0)`, copied down. `F2` is an empty cell.
Finds the row(s) of matched name(s) in column A. Column F can be hidden.
`E3`: `=OFFSET($A$1;F3;1)` 
Selects ID's for the certain name. The formula will be copied down.

Example spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/All_IDs_for_a_name.xls

Answer (score 0):

A vlookup() requires a unique set of values. In your specific case, I would consider running the vlookup() on the user_id as it seems this a is a unique value that identifies each user.

In that regard:

1. Create a new tab (sheet)
2. In column A, copy and paste all "user_id" 's. Make sure to remove duplicates.
3. Column B -> "instance" use a vlookup()
4. Column C -> "name" use a vlookup()
5. Now to get a list of columns with all "Rusty" simply sort column c (Name) from A-Z. Rearrange columns if necessary.

Few reminders with vlookup(). Specifiy range lookup to FALSE. Make sure to use absolute references or better yet - use a table as a reference.

Comment: I have used Vloookup sucessfully, but the table I am looking through does not have the unique ID's, it only has the names + date/time. The ID's are what I am trying to match each instance to.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/All_IDs_for_a_name.xls. Let me know what to change.

Comment: Yours works perfectly, thank you. Only wish I could upvote you.